# Is there a way to get to know if the user is on call while using my app?

Tags: ios, iphone, service, background, phone-call

Is it possible to identify whether the user is on a phone call while using an app.

Here is the scenario:

1. I get a call
2. I accept the call
3. Tap the home button
4. Launch an app

At this point can I tell this app that a call is going on in background?

Getting to know the screen is not a full blown option. Because it makes life difficult when on internet tethering.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the height of the status bar. If it's more than 20px, you're either on a call, or tethering (which is not supported on AT&T, so it must be on a call if you're in the US).

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame
```

Comment: I would hope that nobody is assuming that because tethering is not supported on AT&T that it automatically means they're on a phone call.  There's an awful lot of iPhones that are not US based...

Comment: I'd hope so too, plus I'm still holding out hope for AT&T tethering!

Comment: Whenever I use [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame in a NSLog statement, it shows the frame to be "0". What's up?

Comment: Are you wrapping the frame in NSStringFromCGRect(...)?

Comment: In this case, for example if user has an on going Skype call, how I could tell difference between an on going call and a Skype call.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a public API for any phone state or functionality, so you'll have to rely on side-effects of being on a call.

You can either check the status bar like Ben Gottlieb suggested, or you can try to [initialize an audio recording](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioRecorder/initWithURL:settings:error:), if it fails with an error of already in use, you can be fairly certain the microphone is being used for a call.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on what Ben said, you'll want to subtract [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame from the height you set your View to.